# pandas if-elif statement not creating new dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to create some new pandas dataframe columns within an if-elif statement.

When I run the code, however, no columns are being created by the if-elif statement.

When I take the code outside of the if-elif statement, then pandas creates the columns using the syntax I am using.

What do I need to do to get pandas to create new columns within an if-elif statement?

```
data = '3 months'

if data == '12 months':
    df['calc_year'] = df['quarter'] * 4
elif data == '3 months':
    df['calc_quarter'] = df['year'] / 4
```

I tested my if-elif statement, which works, it just does't create pandas columns.

```
data = 30

if data > 20:
    message = "yep"
elif data <= 20:
    message = "nope"
print(message)
```

Cheers

Comment: share your sample dataframe...

Comment: If you have a df with the columns 'year' and 'quarter', your code should compile. df will be modified as your code runs through the if-elif statement

Comment: The code works. Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works for me.

I just generated the `quarter` & `year` columns with random integers and used your conditions and it gave me the correct output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['quarter'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, 10)
df['year'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, 10)


data = '3 months'

if data == '12 months':
    df['calc_year'] = df['quarter'] * 4
elif data == '3 months':
    df['calc_quarter'] = df['year'] / 4
df


# output
df
Out[8]: 
   quarter  year  calc_quarter
0        1     5          1.25
1        3     2          0.50
2        4     5          1.25
3        1     5          1.25
4        1     3          0.75
5        5     4          1.00
6        1     2          0.50
7        4     4          1.00
8        4     4          1.00
9        1     3          0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

use df.assign instead of assignment, because your question implies that the colum cal_year does not exits

replace

```
if data == '12 months':
    df['calc_year'] = df['quarter'] * 4
elif data == '3 months':
    df['calc_quarter'] = df['year'] / 4
```

with

```
if data == '12 months':
    df = df.assign(calc_year = df['quarter'] * 4)
elif data == '3 months':
    df = df.assign(calc_quarter = df['year'] / 4)
```